# "Can't bind to (...)" and "(...) is not a known element" JS errors when Angular app rendered within a Liferay portlet

Tags: javascript, angular, liferay

I have an Angular 9 app that I would like to make accessible via Liferay 7.x portlet.

When I follow [these steps](https://help.liferay.com/hc/en-us/articles/360029028031-Developing-an-Angular-Application), deploy my portlet and try to render it, I run into issues (reported as JavaScript errors in the browser console):

A. "Can't bind to 'X' since it isn't a known property of 'Y'.

B. "'X' is not a known element:

1. If 'X' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'X' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message."
   The problem is that as far as I can see the modules in question are properly annotated and listed as exports, declarations, etc.

I would appreciate help with resolving these issues. I am happy to jump on a Zoom to demonstrate the details of my config.

Thank you!

Comment: instead of offering zoom, please take the [tour], read [ask] and edit your question with a [mcve].

Comment: What I am looking for is an advice what other things can be at play here, given all the obvious prerequisites for this code to work were met.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the answer here: https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule-faq#what-does-cant-bind-to-x-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-y-mean

> What does "Can't bind to 'x' since it isn't a known property of 'y'" mean?
> This error often means that you haven't declared the directive "x" or
> haven't imported the NgModule to which "x" belongs.
>
> Perhaps you declared "x" in an application sub-module but forgot to
> export it. The "x" class isn't visible to other modules until you add
> it to the exports list.

Comment: In terms of the "Can't bind" error (#A) I believe I have all the required pieces in place:

(...)
import { TelInputModule } from '../controls/tel-input/tel-input.module';
import { MobileTelInputModule } from '../controls/mobile-tel-input/mobile-tel-input.module';
(...)
@NgModule({
   imports: [ (...)
   TelInputModule,
   MobileTelInputModule ],
(...)

In terms of error #B the "X" is declared as an input in the imported module:

export class AngularFileUploaderComponent implements OnChanges, OnInit {
  // Inputs
  @Input()
  config: AngularFileUploaderConfig;

Answer (score 0):

My problems were related to the fact that:

1. The [these steps](https://help.liferay.com/hc/en-us/articles/360029028031-Developing-an-Angular-Application) ask to remove "selector" properties, which is incorrect. When I restored the "selector" properties the problem #1 went away
2. I was ineed missing some module references (problem #2)

Hopefully this helps others, too.